# Zombie cartoon movie or TV show where a little girl loses her dad and is protected by a "good" zombie from other ones

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, zombie

I remember my dad watching a zombie apocalypse animation when I was younger. I don't remember much and I’ve been trying to find it, but I can’t.

I think it starts off like this: a little girl’s dad leaves her in a boat in the water. This little girl meets a zombie, but he’s nice and tries to help her find her dad. He protects her from zombies who are trying to eat her. The nice zombie has a dog who helps too.

I don’t remember much but some scenes.

- They go to a fair that gets taken over by zombies and the good one protects her. At the end they find her dad, but I think he tries and shoots the good zombie
- They find a museum to hide in and one of the mummies comes to life
- I also remember a part where the little girl staples the dog's face back on

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 12):

This sounds pretty much exactly like *[Xombie](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebAnimation/Xombie)*.

[image: Xombie title image]

> Xombie is a Flash animation and comic book series by James Farr. A 6-year-old girl, Zoe, wakes up on a beach with no memory of how she got there. When she wanders into a cemetery, she discovers why the place is so deserted. Zombies begin rising up from the ground, and gather around her. As the zombies close in, a lone figure enters the scene, and proceeds to summarily OWN the gathering zombies...with a shovel. This lone figure is Dirge, a "variant", a zombie that retains cognitive functions, but no memory of who or what he once was. He decides to escort Zoe through miles of zombie-infested wasteland, accompanied by a zombie police-dog called Cerberus, to a nearby human settlement.

### Trailer

Comment: Man that brings back memories. Good ole Newgrounds.

Comment: Memories yes, also a "holy hell I'm old"